# I'm very new to both Android and Eclipse Environment... Unable to run my First App

Tags: android

I am very new to android app development and Eclipse environment. I followed below steps to run my First Android App on my Work Space.

1. Installed Eclipse 4.2(Juno) version.
2. Installed JDK 7U7 64 bit version.
3. Installed ADT Plugin for eclipse.
4. Eclipse-> New Android Project.
5. Without any changes to the code, Just ran the project.

below are console messages, I'm getting:

```
12:03:49,155 INFO  [main] Main  - javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=null
12:03:49,157 INFO  [main] Main  - java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\endorsed
12:03:49,162 INFO  [main] Main  - launchFile: C:\Users\chandu\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.launching\launch\launch.xml
12:03:49,219 FATAL [main] Main  - No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/Users/chandu/workspace/My%20First%20App/res/layout/activity_main.xml
org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.TransformationException: No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/Users/chandu/workspace/My%20First%20App/res/layout/activity_main.xml
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.Main.main(Main.java:73)
Caused by: org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.TransformationException: No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/Users/chandu/workspace/My%20First%20App/res/layout/activity_main.xml
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:214)
    ... 2 more
```

Thanks in advance for any Help on this issue.

Comment: Do you have the [Android SDK installed](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)? You also need to [configure the ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to run the activity_main.xml file. This can happen if your current selection in the Project Explorer view is on the file activity_main.xml. Close the editor for the file and set current selection to the project root node in the Project Explorer, and then try running the application.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. It never worked for me either. I use NetBeans 7 IDE with a plugin.

Instructions are here: http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/pages/Install
and the main page is here: http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid

Good luck

Comment: Apart from installing NetBeans 7 IDE with ADT Plugin, Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Not that I know of. It's also a matter of personal preference.
Eclipse never worked for me no matter which version I tried. Using NetBeans is easy. (Must have JDK, and Android SDK).

Install the plugin in NetBeans, restart NetBeans and start making apps.